# locate doesn't find all the files it should

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locate

I type in `locate gmp.h` at the prompt and get the following:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/linux/igmp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/uapi/linux/igmp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/linux/igmp.h
```

But when I do `ls /usr/include/x86-64-linux-gnu/` I see this:

```
a.out.h  asm  bits  c++  fpu_control.h  gmp.h  gnu  ieee754.h  sys
```

Why isn't `locate` locating `/usr/include/x86-64-linux-gnu/gmp.h`?

edit: `ls -l /usr/include/x64-64-linux-gnu/gmp.h` says this:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/include/x64-64-linux-gnu/gmp.h: No such file or diretory
```

Why would `ls /usr/include/x86-64-linux-gnu/` say it exists when `ls -l /usr/include/x64-64-linux-gnu/gmp.h` says it doesn't?

A screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When were the files you search for created? When did you last update your locate database? (Before or after adding the files) ?

Comment: A few minutes ago. I didn't know the DB had to be updated lol. Doing so resolved the issue - thanks!

Comment: Could you run "ls -l /usr/include/x86-64-linux-gnu/gmp.h" and add the output to your question?

Comment: Done. See my updated question

Comment: Try "ls -l /usr/include/x64-64-linux-gnu". My guess is that the `gmp.h` entry is a symbolic link pointing to a nonexistant file.

Comment: It looks like it exists to me when I do `ls -l`. I've updated my post with a sreenshot..

Comment: I've removed my answer. You've been saying the file is in `/usr/include/x86-64-linux-gnu/`. But according to your screenshot, it's actually in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (underscore instead of dash).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`locate` does not find files on the filesystem. Instead it searches in a database which contains all files.

This database it usually updated once per day, typically around 3 AM.

You can update it manually with command such as `updatedb` (or if not logged in with sufficient credentials: `sudo updatedb`). For more information see `man updatedb`.

---

Based on your post which included /usr/src/linux-headers-3 I assumed that you are running this on a linux distribution. On other operating systems the locate command might work slightly different. E.g. On FreeBSD the command to manually update the locate database is to run `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` which gets weekly updated from `/etc/periodic/weekly/310.locate`.