# configure: error: Unable to locate gmp.h

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, build

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/19894267/569976 I tried the following to no avail:

- `ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/include/gmp.h`
- `--with-gmp=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Both of them get me this error:

```
configure: error: Unable to locate gmp.h
```

When I do `ln /usr/include/x86-64-linux-gnu/` I see this:

```
a.out.h  asm  bits  c++  fpu_control.h  gmp.h  gnu  ieee754.h  sys
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/802022/locate-doesnt-find-all-the-files-it-should.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The answer to that one was to do `sudo updatedb` and that's obviously not an answer for this one as, even after having done that, I'm still getting this error..

Comment: First of all, make sure you're using the correct path to gmp.h when you run `configure` or make the symlink. As in the other question, you're not being consistent about the correct pathname to the file. Next, see if `configure` is leaving its `config.log` file behind when it fails. config.log should list the specific commands that `configure` ran and what exactly happened.

Comment: The path name is correct. Here's my config.log: http://pastebin.com/XcmqhGZr I'm not seeing any specific command mentioned..

Comment: That particular `configure` run appears to have failed because it was interrupted, perhaps because someone hit Ctrl-C. Maybe you could rerun configure and reproduce the error to make sure you have an accurate version of the log.

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried

```
ls /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h
```

Please make sure whether the `gmp.h` file exists.

Maybe you should run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Answer (score 9):

just in case someone having same issue while trying to compile php via phpbrew, although /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h is definitely there and available:

symlink for gmp.h solved this for me

```
ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/include/gmp.h
```

Comment: +1 This is the fix for psptoolchain it helped me to compile it.

Comment: great!, it worked

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem in a Debian/PHP Docker container when running:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install gmp
```

This fixed it for me (run it before the docker-php-ext-install command):

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgmp-dev
RUN ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/include/gmp.h
```

Comment: You saved my day! I was trying to add gmp to a standard wordpress docker image and spent many hours figuring out how to do it